# Unknown characters in LXTerm terminal on Arch linux

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux, character-encoding

I am trying to learn node.js using the learnyounode node from http://nodeschool.io on an arch linux machine running LXDE. I am using the bundled LXTerminal to execute it. However, when I run it, see unknown characters such as these : ������������������������ instead of the lines and bullets in the UI. The UI looks like this:

```
LEARN YOU THE NODE.JS FOR MUCH WIN!                                
Select an exercise and hit Enter to begin                          
����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������  �� HELLO WORLD                                                     ���������������������������  �� BABY STEPS                                                      
�� MY FIRST I/O!                                                   
�� MY FIRST ASYNC I/O!                                             
�� FILTERED LS                                                     
�� MAKE IT MODULAR                                                 
�� HTTP CLIENT                                                     
�� HTTP COLLECT                                                    
�� JUGGLING ASYNC                                                  
�� TIME SERVER                                                     
�� HTTP FILE SERVER                                                
�� HTTP UPPERCASERER                                               
�� HTTP JSON API SERVER                                            
����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������  HELP                                                               ���������������������������  CREDITS                                                            
EXIT
```

I have a feeling that this is possible due to some problem in the charset, but I am not sure how to proceed or fix this.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to fix this. The `LANG` env variable was not set on my machine. I used `#localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and rebooted my machine and it got fixed. Now the characters are rendering properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your locale is well-configured.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale#Setting_per_user_locale

You can also check the "encoding" line in /usr/share/applications/lxterminal.desktop

Comment: Encoding is set to UTF-8 in lxterminal.desktop. Also, locale -a gives me: C POSIX en_US en_US.iso88591 en_US.utf8